# Spring Conversion Service, binding form to a nested object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am having difficulties binding the spring form value to a backing object.
The following are the related parts of the code.

This is from page.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="building" action="addBuilding">
        <div>
            <div>
                <form:label path="buildingName">Building Name:</form:label>
                <form:input path="buildingName" />
                <form:errors path="buildingName"></form:errors>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form:label path="buildingType">Building Type:</form:label>
                <form:select path="buildingType">
                    <form:option value="none">--Select One--</form:option>
                    <form:options items="${buildingTypeList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="typeName"/>
                </form:select>
                <form:errors path="buildingType"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </div>
</form:form>
```

Model classes I want to bind are as the following. I add these for the sake of completeness

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tablename")
class Building {

    @Column
    private buildingName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "buildingType", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private BuildingType buildingType;

    //other fields, getters and setters etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tablename")
class BuildingType {

    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String typeName;

    //getters, setters
}
```

At this point I can see the building type name in the combo-box just fine (in a GET request). The problem happens when I post the form. Itemvalue from combo-box is int and I want to bind it to the buildingType field in the Building model. The code will explain it better I guess. Related controller functions:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addBuilding", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addBuildingPage(Model model) {

    Building building = new Building();
    model.addAttribute("building", building);

    List<BuildingType> buildingTypeList = buildingTypeDao.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("buildingTypeList", buildingTypeList);
    return "addBuilding";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "addBuilding", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitNewBuilding(@ModelAttribute(value = "building") @Valid Building building,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addBuilding";
    }

    model.addAttribute("building", building);

    return "addBuilding";
}
```

I get a cannot cast int to BuildingType exception, after some search I followed the blog post written [here](http://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/binding-nested-objects-complex-properties-with-springs-formselect-tag/). So I decided to write a custom Formatter and use ConversionService.
This is the formatter class

```
@Component
public class BuildingTypeFormatter implements Formatter<BuildingType> {

    @Autowired
    private BuildingTypeDao buildingTypeDao;

    @Override
    public String print(BuildingType buildingType, Locale arg1) {
    return buildingType.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public BuildingTypeDBO parse(String id, Locale arg1) throws ParseException {
    return buildingTypeDao.findOne(Long.parseLong(id));
    }
}
```

And this is the spring configuration class. (I don't use xml configuration.)

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "my.packages" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BuildingTypeDBOFormatter formatter;

    public MvcConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean(name = "conversionService")
    public FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService() {
        FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        Set<Formatter<?>> formatters = new HashSet<Formatter<?>>();
        formatters.add(formatter);
        bean.setFormatters(formatters);

        return bean;
    }
```

I think I need to register conversion service as explained in the blog post. Using and init binder in my controller like this.

```
@Autowired
ConversionService conversionService;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setConversionService(conversionService);
}
```

The problem is I get the following exception when using setConversionException. And when I debug it I see that binder is initialized with a default conversionService.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBinder is already initialized with ConversionService
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.setConversionService(DataBinder.java:562)
at my.package.controller.MyController.initBinder(MyController.java:138)
```

I came across with many answers suggesting setConversionService but it just doesn't work, how can I fix this? (PS: Sorry for the long post, but I think there may be couple of ways to fix this, so I preferred to post the whole thing.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try add custom property editor in your controller

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {

    binder.registerCustomEditor(BuildingType.class, "buildingType", new PropertyEditorSupport() {

        public void setAsText(String text) {
            Long buildingTypeId = Long.parseLong(text);
            BuildingType buildingType = (BuildingType) buildingTypeDao.findOne(buildingTypeId);
            setValue(buildingType);               
        }
    });

}
```